# I can't ssh into an ec2 instrance from script

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2

```
if [ $1 = 1 ]; then 
    echo "option 1"
    ssh -i swarm-nodes.pem ec2-user@18.255.33.
elif [ $1 = 2 ]; then 
    ssh -i swarm-nodes.pem ec2-user@18.188.124.
elif [ $1 = 3 ]; then 
    ssh -i swarm-nodes.pem ec2-user@3.137.220.
fi
```

copying and pasting any of those ssh lines right into command line works just fine.. when running as a script, however, i.e. ./myscript 1, it times out..
So, I figured I'd ask here

Comment: Can you please run your ssh commands in the script with `-v` to show what exactly happens?

Comment: yes, let me try, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I heard from a good friend that using the DNS Name instead of the IP Address works.